# Flatlist data not showing up on screen

Tags: react-native, expo

Trying to make a simple to-do list. My AddTodo component works fine and I don't believe it is causing the issue but my Flatlist does not show the data. I have no idea why as there are no errors. The issue appears with or without the scroll view.

I've tried messing around with the width and height of the items and the list itself but nothing seems to do the trick.

my mainTodo file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import AddTodo from './AddTodo';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class MainTodo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInput: '',
      todos: [
        { id: 0, title: 'walk rocky', completed: false },
        { id: 1, title: 'pickup dinner', completed: false }
      ]
    };
  }

  addNewTodo() {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.unshift({
      id: todos.length + 1,
      todo: this.state.textInput,
      completed: false
    });

    this.setState({
      todos,
      textInput: ''
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AddTodo
          textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
          addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
          textInput={this.state.textInput}
        />
        <ScrollView>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            data={this.state.todos}
            extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <TodoItem todoItem={item} />
              );
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MainTodo;
```

my TodoItem file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.todoItem}>
          <Text style={(todoItem.completed) ? { color: '#aaaaaa' } : { color: '#313131' }}>
            {todoItem.title}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  todoItem: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#DDD',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 15
  }
});

export default TodoItem;
```

Under my addtodo component nothing shows up, it's just a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the `maintodo` file you are rendering the `AddTodo component` but i didn't see your `AddTodo component`. So you can update your code accordingly.

In the `TodoItem` remove the `style` applied to `TouchableOpacity` so that your code looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;

    return (
      <View> 
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.todoItem}>
          <Text style={(todoItem.completed) ? { color: '#aaaaaa' } : { color: '#313131' }}>
            {todoItem.title}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default TodoItem;
```

And in the `MainTodo`

update your `addNewTodo` function as

```
addNewTodo = () => {
    const todo = {
      id: this.state.todos.length,
      title: this.state.textInput,
      completed: false
    }
    this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos, todo ], textInput: ""})
  }
```

create the `TextInput` and `Button` with parent `View` as `flexDirection: "row"` and so when `TextInput` is changed it's value is `set in the textInput` and when `Button` is pressed it will create new `object` and add it to the `todos` and set the value of `TextInput` to empty.

and final code can be as

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, ScrollView, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class MainTodo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInput: '',
      todos: [
        { id: 0, title: 'walk rocky', completed: false },
        { id: 1, title: 'pickup dinner', completed: false }
      ]
    };
  }

  addNewTodo = () => {
    const todo = {
      id: this.state.todos.length,
      title: this.state.textInput,
      completed: false
    }
    this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos, todo ], textInput: ""})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}>
      <View style={{flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
      <TextInput  style={{borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "black"}} onChangeText={textInput => this.setState({textInput})} placeholder="Enter todo text" value={this.state.textInput} />
         <Button onPress={this.addNewTodo} title="Add todo" />
         </View>

          <FlatList
           contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}
            data={this.state.todos}
            extraData={this.state.todos}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <TodoItem todoItem={item} />
              );
            }}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MainTodo;
```

Comment: I tried it and still have the same problem as the first part shows up without the second.

Comment: I ended up taking the flex out of the parent view component and that solved the problem. Not sure why.

Comment: Are you sure my solution is not working I tested in snack it is fine

Answer (score 0):

**use the code**

> **mainTodo file:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import AddTodo from './AddTodo';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class MainTodo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textInput: '',
      todos: [
        { id: 0, title: 'walk rocky', completed: false },
        { id: 1, title: 'pickup dinner', completed: false }
      ]
    };
  }

  addNewTodo() {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.unshift({
      id: todos.length + 1,
      todo: this.state.textInput,
      completed: false
    });

    this.setState({
      todos,
      textInput: ''
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <AddTodo
          textChange={textInput => this.setState({ textInput })}
          addNewTodo={() => this.addNewTodo()}
          textInput={this.state.textInput}
        />
        <ScrollView>
          <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            data={this.state.todos}
            extraData={this.state}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <TodoItem todoItem={item} />
              );
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MainTodo;
```

> **TodoItem file:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const todoItem = this.props.todoItem;

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.todoItem}>
          <Text style={(todoItem.completed) ? { color: '#aaaaaa' } : { color: '#313131' }}>
            {todoItem.title}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  todoItem: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderBottomColor: '#DDD',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor:'red',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingLeft: 15
  }
});
export default TodoItem;
```